# What is angamardana yoga system?

Tags: yoga, yoga-sutras, spirituality

I would like to know specific details about **angamardana yoga**. Things I am interested in knowing about it are:

1. Basic info about angamardana system for a beginner.
2. Postures/poses associated with it.
3. Any specific rules or regulations associated with it.

Any other useful information would be helpful indeed.